# How to draw a selection rectangle between OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, rectangles

I have code that lets the user select a rectangle on an image that will become a *hole* in the form. But before I create this *hole* from combined regions, I want to mark this rectangle area with a red color.

So in this picture, an area with the size of the small rectangle should be drawn red during dragging with the mouse:

[image]

My code till so far is:

```
private
    { Private declarations }
    Point1, Point2: TPoint;
    function ClientToWindow(const p: TPoint): TPoint;
    procedure AdjustRegions;


function TForm1.ClientToWindow(const p: TPoint): TPoint;
begin
  Result := ClientToScreen(p);
  Result.X := Result.X - Left;
  Result.Y := Result.Y - Top;
end;

procedure TForm1.AdjustRegions;
var
  rForm, rWindow: hrgn;
  headerHeight: Integer;
begin

  if ((Point2.X - Point1.X) <= 0) or ((Point2.Y - Point1.Y) <= 0) then
    SetWindowRgn(Self.Handle, 0, True)
  else
  begin
    rForm := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height);
    rWindow := CreateRectRgn(
      ClientToWindow(Point1).X,
      ClientToWindow(Point1).Y,
      ClientToWindow(Point2).X,
      ClientToWindow(Point2).Y);

    CombineRgn(rForm, rForm, rWindow, RGN_DIFF);
    SetWindowRgn(Self.Handle, rForm, True);

  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
FillChar(Point1, SizeOf(Point1), 0);
FillChar(Point2, SizeOf(Point2), 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
AdjustRegions;
end;

procedure TForm1.img1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
Point1.X := X;
Point1.Y := Y;
end;

procedure TForm1.img1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
if X > Point1.X then
    Point2.X := X
  else
    begin
      Point2.X := Point1.X;
      Point1.X := X;
    end;
  if Y > Point1.Y then
    Point2.Y := Y
  else
    begin
      Point2.Y := Point1.Y;
      Point1.Y := Y;
    end;

  AdjustRegions;
end;
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Any suggestions of what? What is the problem?

Comment: The given code doesn't *draw* anything. Why are you using that code at all?

Comment: The OP at least made SOME effort, despite not understanding how to draw anything at all on a TCanvas.  Looking at the code, not only is there no drawing code, there's no idea that you even needed something to draw on (like a paintbox, or to write a TCustomControl that paints itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the canvas in the `OnMouseMove` event.

This could look like:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PaintBox1: TPaintBox;
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PaintBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PaintBox1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    procedure PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FSelecting: Boolean;
    FSelection: TRect;
    procedure AdjustFormRegion;
    function ClientToWindow(const P: TPoint): TPoint;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.AdjustFormRegion;
var
  FormRegion: HRGN;
  HoleRegion: HRGN;
begin
  FSelection.NormalizeRect;
  if FSelection.IsEmpty then
    SetWindowRgn(Handle, 0, True)
  else
  begin
    FormRegion := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height);
    HoleRegion := CreateRectRgn(
      ClientToWindow(FSelection.TopLeft).X,
      ClientToWindow(FSelection.TopLeft).Y,
      ClientToWindow(FSelection.BottomRight).X,
      ClientToWindow(FSelection.BottomRight).Y);
    CombineRgn(FormRegion, FormRegion, HoleRegion, RGN_DIFF);
    SetWindowRgn(Handle, FormRegion, True);
  end;
end;

function TForm1.ClientToWindow(const P: TPoint): TPoint;
begin
  Result := PaintBox1.ClientToScreen(P);
  Dec(Result.X, Left);
  Dec(Result.Y, Top);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AdjustFormRegion;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FSelection.Left := X;
  FSelection.Top := Y;
  FSelecting := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if FSelecting then
  begin
    FSelection.Right := X;
    FSelection.Bottom := Y;
    PaintBox1.Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FSelecting := False;
  FSelection.Right := X;
  FSelection.Bottom := Y;
  PaintBox1.Invalidate;
  AdjustFormRegion;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Rectangle(FSelection);
end;

end.
```

Some general remarks:

- You do not have to initialize a `TPoint` to zero, this will be done automatically. See [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Methods#Constructors):

  > Because a constructor always clears the storage it allocates for a new object, all fields start with a value of zero (ordinal types), nil (pointer and class types), empty (string types), or Unassigned (variants). Hence there is no need to initialize fields in a constructor's implementation except to nonzero or nonempty values.
- Although an Image component can be used for custom drawing, it is designed for showing pictures. I suggest you change it into a PaintBox (or the Form itself).
- Since you use Delphi XE5, make use of its `TRect` members like `NormalizeRect`, `IsEmpty`, etc...

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion! but I'm using a `TImage` component in my software of remote assistence for receive updated printscreens. So, `PaintBox` component will go works fine in my case, if I replace the `TImage` component?

Comment: Yes. Paint your screen print with `PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(PrintScreen);` prior to drawing the rectangle. You cán paint on an Image's canvas too, but previous drawing will last, so have to clear it manually, which results in the same code as with this paint box.

Comment: how make based in your same suggestion above, but this time, using `TImage` component? `PaintBox` is being very hard for I adjust to my software, because the printscreens are loaded from a `MemoryStream` to `TImage`. Waiting...

Comment: Then remove the `PaintBox1.Invalidate` calls, and move the paint code to the `OnMouseMove` event handler, using the Image's canvas.

Comment: OK, in `MouseDown` event, the `Timage` component stays with a white color, this is normal? and how I "clean" the `TRect´ after generate the final result (the rectangle with the hole)? because after when I click in `Timage` again, the `TRect` red still stays in `TImage`. [Here](http://pastebin.com/45ECu6zg) is my code now.

Comment: If your image indeed shows content from a remote machine then I would recommend not to drawing the selection rectangle directly on it. Why? Because you will lose that selection rectangle as soon as you update your image with the latest screenshot. So instead you might want to place another control on top of your image and render the selection rectangle to it. Or even better make resizable control that can be automatically resized as you are moving your mouse cursor while having mouse button down.

Comment: As another option you might want to use Graphics32 library instead of default VCL TImage component. Why? TImage32 that ships with Graphics32 library supports multiple layers so you can be updating each layer separately. And you can blend multiple layers into each other using Alpha blending which would allow you to render semitransparent selection rectangle. Also it will offer you much higher performance as it is using hardware acceleration for graphic rendering.

Comment: @SilverWarior, considering your observation about `TImage` component, Then the solution of code suggested by NGLN, is the better. Thank you very much!

Comment: @NGLN, Thank you very much, your suggestion of code above solved my trouble and worked very perfectly in my software of remote assistence!